# Issue with XmlStreamReader not getting the last xml element content

Tags: apex, xml, xmlnode, xmlparsing

I have the following code to parse an xml script below

```
class Cell {
    string data;
}

Integer rowCounter = 0;
List<Cell> cells = new List<Cell>();
Map<Integer, List<Cell>> timeEntryMap = new Map<Integer, List<Cell>>();

//See the xmloutput after this apex codes.
XmlStreamReader xsr = new XmlStreamReader(xmlOutput);
while(xsr.hasNext())
{
    if(xsr.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT) {
        if(xsr.getLocalName() == 'Row') {
            rowCounter++;
            timeEntryMap.put(rowCounter, cells);
            cells = new List<Cell>();
        }

        if (xsr.getLocalName() == 'Cell') {
            Cell cell = getCellData(xsr);
            cells.add(cell);
        }
    }
    xsr.next();
}

Cell getCellData(XmlStreamReader reader) {
    string dataContainer = '';
    Cell cell = new Cell();

    while(reader.hasNext()){
        if (reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.END_ELEMENT)
            break;
        else if (reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.CHARACTERS){
            if (!String.isBlank(reader.getText())){
                dataContainer += reader.getText();
            }
        }
        reader.next();
    }

    cell.data = dataContainer;

    return cell;
}

for (Integer key : timeEntryMap.keySet()){
    system.debug('===============ROW Start====================');
    for (Integer i = 0;i < timeEntryMap.get(key).size();i++){
        system.debug(timeEntryMap.get(rowKey)[i].data);
    }
    system.debug('===============ROW End====================');
}
```

Here is the **xmlOutput** that I am trying to parse..

```
<Table>
  <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Default">
      <Data ss:Type="String">19c46fb7-5314-4f8d-b6b5...</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Date">
      <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2016-06-07T00:00:00</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Date">
      <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2016-06-05T00:00:00</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Date">
      <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2016-06-11T00:00:00</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Default">
      <Data ss:Type="String">urn:tenant:user...</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Number">
      <Data ss:Type="Number">2.00</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Number">
      <Data ss:Type="Number">0.00</Data>
    </Cell>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Default">
      <Data ss:Type="String">19c46fb7-5314-4f8d-b6b5...</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Date">
      <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2016-06-10T00:00:00</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Date">
      <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2016-06-05T00:00:00</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Date">
      <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2016-06-11T00:00:00</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Default">
      <Data ss:Type="String">urn:tenant:user...</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Number">
      <Data ss:Type="Number">2.00</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Number">
      <Data ss:Type="Number">0.00</Data>
    </Cell>
  </Row>
</Table>
```

This maybe somehow similar to this [issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/12724/35032).

Was this really an issue with `XmlStreamReader` so the only way to get this thing to work is to use `XML Dom Reader`? I am taking the `XML Dom reader`  as my last resort if this could not really get to work with XmlStreamReader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why your code isn't working. Most of the time the code is a lot easier to write (and therefore easier to maintain in the future) using the [Dom](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_namespace_Dom.htm) classes as they work at a more abstract level.

For your XML the basic code would look something like this:

```
Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
doc.load(xml);

Dom.XmlNode table = doc.getRootElement();
for (Dom.XmlNode row : table.getChildElements()) {
   if (row.getName() == 'Row') {
       for (Dom.XmlNode cell : row.getChildElements()) {
           if (cell.getName() == 'Cell') {
               for (Dom.XmlNode data : cell.getChildElements()) {
                   if (data.getName() == 'Data') {
                       String text = data.getText();
                       ...
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer my question but I agree with you on  **"code is a lot easier to write (and therefore easier to maintain in the future) using the Dom classes as they work at a more abstract level."** I updated the logic on how do I read the xml response into something like you did in the above code. Thus, it fixes my issue. Thank you!